# How can I format my checkboxes in a form using CSS? I want a simple look and feel

Tags: css, forms, checkbox, formatting

I have searched many sites, including this one and I cannot get this to work. I have a simple form [Job Application](http://myfriedpickles.com/contact.php)  where you can see the example of the formatting not working.

I would like just a simple checkbox, nothing fancy, using CSS to format it. I have tried multiple examples and it just never comes out right.

```css
form {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
  background: linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 750px;
  height: 1200px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: inset 1px solid #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

label {
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

input {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}

fieldset p {
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
}

input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {
  flex: none;
}

textarea#feedback {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label>Position: check all you are interested in </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="job[]" value="General Pickle Production">General Pickle Production</input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="job[]" value="Fryer">Fryer</input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="job[]" value="Sales">Sales</input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="job[]" value="Manager">Manager</input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="job[]" value="Overnights">Overnights</input>
</p>
```

Is there just a simple way to resolve this?

Comment: Have you had a look at bootstrap? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Comment: What do you want to achive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achive.

If not please comment what you need.

Remember that for HTML thers no `</input>` tag. But there is on XHTML, so depends on what you are using.

```css
form {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
  background: linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 750px;
  height: 1200px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: inset 1px solid #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

label {
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 30px;
  float: left;
}

fieldset p {
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
}

input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {
  flex: none;
}

textarea#feedback {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}

p {display: inline-block}
```

```html
<label>Position: check all you are interested in </label>
<div>
  <p>General Pickle Production<input type="checkbox" name="job[]" value="General Pickle Production"></p>
   <p>Fryer<input type="checkbox" name="job[]" value="Fryer"></p>
  <p>Sales<input id="3" type="checkbox" name="job[]" value="Sales"></p>
  <p>Manager<input id="4" type="checkbox" name="job[]" value="Manager"></p>
  <p>Overnights<input id="5" type="checkbox" name="job[]" value="Overnights"></p>
</div>

<input type="text">
```

Comment: I can see how this code made the checkbox field look good, but then it messes up the other input="text" fields. See my Job Application page now. I can see what the <p> tag is doing now for the checkbox field, I think ultimately I would like to have the options span across the page: so the form is not so long as well.

Comment: ok, so i edited my answer. I made the checkboxes horizontal and added a text input. Also change some css not to mess with the text type. Is this what u needed??

Comment: My form is the cleanest it has looked so far. If you preview the form, link found in my original post, you can see the checkbox options are vertical using the <p> tag. I am looking to have the options be horizontal checkboxes so the form itself is not so long. If I take the <p> tags out it gets all messed up.

Comment: nice. Now make the `p` and `input[type=checkbox] ` via css`display:inline-block`. Then play with this elements width

Comment: That did - thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by simple look and feel. But there is a way to apply almost any kind of styles (including simple one) to the inputs with type checkbox.

Here is the idea.

- Create label tag for each input
- Make label tag have same value for "for" attr as for "id" attr of corresponding input tag
- Hide input with css
- Style label as you wish using :checked pseudo selector on input tag

Your inputs will work the same, no worries, since checkbox is triggered when you click label just as same as for clicking the input itself.

Made a small pen for you, please make sure to change stuff for you own implementation this is a quick draw, here is the link --> https://codepen.io/nikolamitic/pen/jYPwqq

```
<form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" id="some-checkbox">
  <label for="some-checkbox" class="checkbox-label"><i class="check-mark">&#10004;</i></label>
</form>

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label.checkbox-label .check-mark {
  opacity: 1;
}

label.checkbox-label {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.check-mark {
  opacity: 0;
  color: tomato;
}
```